# Apache Spark - how to create difference columns for every column in dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark `DataFrame` with ID and a bunch of numeric columns and for every column besides ID, I'm trying to generate a column of lagged differences grouped by ID.

For instance if I have this `DataFrame`

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| ID| var1| var2| var3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|    1|    3|    2|
|  1|    2|    4|    2|
|  1|    3|    1|    3|
|  2|    1|    3|    4|
|  2|    1|    2|    1|
|  2|    1|    1|    1|
|  2|    3|    3|    1|
|  3|   -1|    0|    0|
|  3|    2|   -1|    2|
|  3|    0|    4|    0|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

I would expect the output to be something like this:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+----------+
| ID| var1| var2| var3| var1_diff| var2_diff| var3_diff|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|    1|    3|    2|      null|      null|      null|
|  1|    2|    4|    2|         1|         1|         0|
|  1|    3|    1|    3|         1|        -3|         1|
|  2|    1|    3|    4|      null|      null|      null|
|  2|    1|    2|    1|         0|        -1|        -3|
|  2|    1|    1|    1|         0|        -1|         0|
|  2|    3|    3|    1|         2|         2|         0|
|  3|   -1|    0|    0|      null|      null|      null|
|  3|    2|   -1|    2|         3|        -1|         2|
|  3|    0|    4|    0|        -2|         3|        -2|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+----------+
```

Where the `_diff` columns are the original columns subtracting their lags. My `DataFrame` has much more than 3 variables, so I'd want to be able to generate lagged differences for an arbitrarily high number of columns. i.e. I don't want to create the `_diff` columns one by one.

Any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `lag` as you pointed out in the function with Spark Window function.

You can generate a dynamic expression by storing the columns that you need to find the difference for.

The following will basically create an expression of type `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` which you can use over your original dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"id")

//df.columns returns all the columns of the dataframe
//union is used to include the original columns in the expression
//expr looks like : (var1 - lag(var1) over window) as var1_diff ...

val expr = df.columns.map(col(_)) union df.columns.filterNot(_.toLowerCase.equals("id")).map { x => (col(x) - lag(col(x),1).over(w) ).as(s"${x}_diff") }
```

And then you can execute the expression generated above over your dataframe using `select`

```
df.select(expr:_*).show
+---+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id|var1|var2|var3|var1_diff|var2_diff|var3_diff|
+---+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1|   1|   3|   2|     null|     null|     null|
|  1|   2|   4|   2|        1|        1|        0|
|  1|   3|   1|   3|        1|       -3|        1|
|  3|  -1|   0|   0|     null|     null|     null|
|  3|   2|  -1|   2|        3|       -1|        2|
|  3|   0|   4|   0|       -2|        5|       -2|
|  2|   1|   3|   4|     null|     null|     null|
|  2|   1|   2|   1|        0|       -1|       -3|
|  2|   1|   1|   1|        0|       -1|        0|
|  2|   3|   3|   1|        2|        2|        0|
+---+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go with `foldLeft` (a powerful api in scala)

```
//assuming that the column ID is at the front
val tailColumns = df.columns.tail

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("ID")

tailColumns.foldLeft(df){(tempdf, colName) => tempdf.withColumn(colName+"_diff", col(colName)-lag(col(colName), 1).over(windowSpec))}.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
|ID |var1|var2|var3|var1_diff|var2_diff|var3_diff|
+---+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
|1  |1   |3   |2   |null     |null     |null     |
|1  |2   |4   |2   |1        |1        |0        |
|1  |3   |1   |3   |1        |-3       |1        |
|3  |-1  |0   |0   |null     |null     |null     |
|3  |2   |-1  |2   |3        |-1       |2        |
|3  |0   |4   |0   |-2       |5        |-2       |
|2  |1   |3   |4   |null     |null     |null     |
|2  |1   |2   |1   |0        |-1       |-3       |
|2  |1   |1   |1   |0        |-1       |0        |
|2  |3   |3   |1   |2        |2        |0        |
+---+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

**Note: I have used ID in orderBy which is not recomended, recomended to generate a separate column preserving the order of rows and use that instead of ID**

I hope the answer is helpful